# SWI-Prolog Replacing an Atom value by another value

Tags: prolog, concatenation, swi-prolog

I am a newbie to SWI-Prolog and am facing an issue. So I have these Atoms named GUID1 and GUID2. Initially suppose GUID1 = 'ABC'. After following statement:

```
gensym(GUID1,GUID2)
```

GUID2 becomes 'ABC1'. Now I need to concatenate this ABC1 with prefix say 'X', the result by concatenate is received in new Atom say NGUID2. I used

```
atom_concat(P, GUID2, NGUID2),
```

P has 'X' as the value.

For now, NGUID2 is successfully bound to 'XABC1'. But For some reason I want this 'XABC1' value to bind to GUID2 as otherwise, it will complicate my other work. Basically I want to reassign GUID2 to value of NGUID2.

Edit 1: I tried `b_setval(GUID2, NGUID2)` but, it is not updating GUID2. So I'm still stuck.

Edit 2: So as per one of the comments I will specify why I want to do this.

[Predicate definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al9aT.png)

This is the original implementation which I need to modify. And When I call the predicate with following call.

[Calling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb64c.png)

The Clone_ID in calling predicate gets bound to the GUID value +1,+2,+3... Eg if GUID value is ABC then Clone_ID will become ABC1 for first call, ABC2 for second call and so on. But Now I want to append a prefix X to Each new value of Clone_ID, so it should be something like XABC1, XABC2, ... and so on. How should I modify the function definition in-order to do so.

Comment: Can't 'ABC1' be a temporary variable, named e.g. GUID1Num? This way, you can set GUID2 as you like, because it won't already have been set to 'ABC1'.

Comment: @brebs the value of GUID2 is coming from GUID1 which cannot be changed and I want to uphold both, the result of gensysm and my concatenation in GUID2.

Comment: Prolog doesn't work that way. Explain *why* you're trying to do the impossible, and we can help to rewrite it. Here's a relevant previous discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282034/forcing-variable-to-reassign-prolog

Comment: @brebs I have added why I want to do what I do. Please help me rewrite it.

Comment: Presumably, is easiest to use https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nb_setval/2 in a centralized "add unique ID number" predicate. This is more convenient than `assert`. Note that its first argument is a name, *not* a variable as you tried earlier with `b_setval`.

Comment: @brebs So can you suggest what should be the argument of nb_setval() in this scenario?

Comment: Hi all, Quick update: I rewrote the code myself, I was doing just a minor error which was "I took atom name's starting as a number!!". Just wondering why prolog does not give error statements, it will take eternity if some minor mistake, like mentioned, is there.